# Stsrt .exe installer on Domain Computers WMI process

Tags: vb.net, network-programming, wmi

I'm working on a Windows VB.net form that is checking Domain Computers for the presence of anti-virus software. If it is missing the application copies the Installer to the Domain Computers local C:\ drive. Everything is working correctly but the final piece of the puzzle is to invoke the .exe installer as a background process using something like WMI Win32_Process.Create. I have the Domain Computers that need the software in a .txt file but I am struggling to get this method to work. I realise PowerShell may be better suited for this but this will be used in 70 different sites which are not consistently setup. The application allows for easy user interaction (site IT engineers) rather than them tweaking scripts. Any suggestions about the best way to implement this would be much appreciated.

What I have so far......

```
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles InstallButton.Click

    Dim PCsource As String = "C:\Path\Install.txt"
    Dim Check As String
    Dim strCommand As String = "Antivirus.exe"

    If System.IO.File.Exists(PCsource) = True Then
        Dim Computer As New System.IO.StreamReader(PCsource)
        Do While Computer.Peek() <> -1
            Check = Computer.ReadLine()


        Loop
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an updating program that after downloading the necessary files it needs starts the exe file. It uses the following code:

```
    Dim MyPath As String
    MyPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)
    Dim SoftwarePath As String = MyPath & "\Program.exe"

    If File.Exists(SoftwarePath) Then
        Process.Start(SoftwarePath, "")

        Application.Exit()
    End If
```

Comment: Thank you RussAwesome, the problem is Process.Start only seems to work on the local machine. The application needs to launch the process on all the network Domain Computers in the .txt file

Comment: You may be able to use 
`Process.Start(@"\\Server-Name\Shared Folder\Program.exe");` as the `@` character prevents the `\` being escaped as part of the UNC path.